# C# calling stored procedure with user define type throws error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to invoke a stored procedure from my C# asp.net core 2.1 using the following code. But getting the error as shown below. What is wrong with my code? Can anyone please point me out? Thanks

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

foreach(var status in requiredStatuses)
{
    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
    row["Value"] = status;
    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}

string executeSpSql = @"EXEC [dbo].[GetCourseDelegatesByStatus] @Year, @CourseId, @DelegateUserId, @Statuses";
object[] parameters = new object[] {
    new SqlParameter("@Year", year) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int },
    new SqlParameter("@CourseId", courseId) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int },
    new SqlParameter("@DelegateUserId", delegateUserId) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier },
    new SqlParameter("@Statuses", SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        Value = dataTable,
        TypeName = "[dbo].[StringList]"
    }
};

var result = await _context.SimpleCourseDelegate.FromSql(executeSpSql, parameters).ToListAsync();
```

and my sql stored procedure signature would be like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCourseDelegatesByStatus]
    @Year INT = NULL,
    @CourseId INT = NULL,
    @DelegateUserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
    @Statuses StringList READONLY
```

Error:

```
{"error":"One or more errors occurred. (The parameterized query '(@Year int,@CourseId int,@DelegateUserId uniqueidentifier,@Statu' expects the parameter '@CourseId', which was not supplied.)"}
```

Adding the following fixed the issue:

```
new SqlParameter("@CourseId", DBNull.Value) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int },
```

Comment: The code you've posted looks OK to me.  Go through everything with a fine tooth comb and find out where CourseID is missing.

Comment: I would like use this method instead: CALL myStore({0})

Comment: You are probably passing a null value to the parameter, but this makes the FromSql call remove the parameter from the collection, thus it fails because it's missing a needed parameter. See [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063025/how-to-pass-null-parameters-to-context-query-type-in-entity-framework-core-2-1) and pass a DbNull instead when you encounter a null object.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Ruyter mentioned, adding a DBNull fixed this error:

```
new SqlParameter("@CourseId", DBNull.Value) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int },
```